# OnSend fired twice after attachment reminder

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

In Outlook Web Add-In, I'm trying to intercept `OnSend` event which is triggered when sending an email.

I used this [example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) in GitHub which is working fine.

If I include the word "attachment" in the email body and I click Send button, `OnSend` event is fired once and a pop-up modal window shows up with this message:

> **Attachment reminder**
>
> You may have forgotten to attach a file.

with **Send** and **Don't send** buttons. If click **Send**, `OnSend` event get fired twice: 2 times after clicking `Send` button within attachment reminder. I was expecting only one event like the first **Send**.

How can I make `OnSend` event fire once after the attachment reminder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be unintentional behavior, essentially a defect that we will look into fixing. ItemSend event should inter operate with forgotten attachment detection nicely, and should only be raised once for any email and only after the forgotten attachment detection happened. In the mean time, you'll need to come up with a workaround. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may be able to use [custom properties API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/CustomProperties?product=outlook) to set a property indicating that message has been processed already to avoid duplicate processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - if the message submission is canceled and the message is then resubmitted, the event is fired again. You can have a list of message entry ids that you processed - add the id to that list when OnSend fires, then check if the message is in that list when the event fires again next time.

Comment: If I click Send button within the attachment reminder, `OnSend` will fire 2 times (without counting the first `OnSend` event)

Comment: Is not about to handle the issue, it is about the fact that `OnSend` fired twice is not expected behavior. When I said twice it means 2 times after clicking Send button from attachment reminder without counting the first OnSend (before attachment reminder) which is expected to fire only once.

Comment: If you want to have it fixed, you need to open a support case with Microsoft. Posting about this issue on SO won't do anything.